# How to autocomplete HTML tags in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: html, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I need to auto complete HTML tags in Sublime Text 3.
For instance:

When I am typing 
`<h1`  after typing `>`

I should get `<h1>|<h2>`

**Note:** The pipe means the position of cursor.
And auto complete should be **Without TAB**

**Note:** This question may have been asked before but those answer aren't satisfactory as they are irreverent now.

**Thanks**

Comment: autocomplete works in a different way on sublime. Once you are done with the start tag you need to write </ and then the remaining code will be auto-completed.

Comment: Yes I do know that. But, I was wondering if there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah you can try [Auto Close](https://github.com/sh4nks/auto_close).

This will fullfill your requirement.

If you don't know how to install package. You can follow following steps.

1. First open package manager `ctrl+shift+p`
2. Search and select Add Repository. Then paste the github link.
3. After that again open package manager. Search and select Install Package.
4. Search and select Auto Close

Then your are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Auto Close](https://github.com/sh4nks/auto_close) Plugin can help you to auto close different types of HTML tags. 
This is a simple plugin that auto closes HTML tags right after '>'.

Inspired by Geany's HTML auto close functionality.

Comment: Its show this 
 error message 
   `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wS4GxBnwOcomQQiljksXpBqT0So8bJan/view`

Comment: @xN77 This package above work well for me. You already install this sublime package in the right way?